# Preparing a multi-dimension header Excel file for Tableau

Tags: excel, tableau-api, data-cleaning

I have data formatted like this:

[image: Structure of the Doc]

I marked the "multi-level" header on the x-axis in orange.

Goal is to analyse it in Tableau.

How might I get aggregates by level and clean this source data?

Comment: Best practice is to eliminate the multi-level header, and use a single-level one. There are no reasons to use multiple lines as header, instead of a single line, no kind of information that can be stored in multiple lines that cannot be stored in a single one

Comment: How to do this, in that particular example. Thanks so far

Comment: Ahn, select the first 5 lines and delete them?

Comment: Then Id loose all the aggregation logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this through loading it into MSQL Server and unpivot the data to get one peace of data per row.